# How to do a simple mod re-write with no subdirectories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All of my pages are something like:

```
domain.com/secondary.php?slug=whatever-the-slug-is
```

but I want them to look like:

```
domain.com/whatever-the-slug-is
```

---

I've tried a ton of variations but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/secondary\.php\?slug=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /secondary.php?slug=$1 [L]
```